# Springboot Implement custom filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I need help implementing a custom filter on spring. I need to force password change when required to do so. Basically the user should not be able to go anywhere except password reset page. However I am getting: Too many redirects error message and the password change is not doing anything.

**Here is my configuration class:**

```
    public class SecurityConfiguration {
    
        @Autowired
        private UserService userService;
    
    
        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }
    
        @Bean
        public AuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
            DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
            provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
            provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
            return provider;
        }
    
        @Bean
        public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
            return new AppUserDetailsService();
        }
    
        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
            http.authorizeHttpRequests(request ->
                            request.requestMatchers("/login", "/", "/css/**", "/login","/login.do", "/api/**").permitAll()
                                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    )
                    //.csrf().disable()
                    .formLogin(form -> form
                            .loginPage(LOGIN_URL)
                            .loginProcessingUrl("/login.do")
                            .failureUrl("/login?error")
                            .usernameParameter("username")
                            .passwordParameter("password")
                            .defaultSuccessUrl("/home"))
                    .logout(logout -> logout
                            .permitAll()
                            .logoutUrl("/logout")
                            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout"));
                   
            http.addFilterAfter(forcePasswordChangeFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    
            return http.build();
        }
    
        @Bean
        public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
            return (web) -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers(
                    "/resources/**",
                    "/static/**",
                    "/css/**",
                    "/js/**",
                    "/assets/**",
                    "/img/**",
                    "/images/**",
                    "/api/**"
            );
        }
    
        @Bean
       public ForcePasswordChangeFilter forcePasswordChangeFilter(){
            return new ForcePasswordChangeFilter(userService);
        }
    
    
    }
```

**Here is my custom filter class:**

```
    public class ForcePasswordChangeFilter extends GenericFilter {
    
        private final UserService userService;
    
        public ForcePasswordChangeFilter(UserService userService) {
            this.userService = userService;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest request,
                             ServletResponse response,
                             FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
            if (userService.isAuthenticated()) {
                User user  = userService.authenticatedUser();
                if (user.getShouldChangePassword()) {
                    var httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
                    httpResponse.sendRedirect("/change-password");
                    return;
                }
            }
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
```

Here is my controller:

```
    @Controller
    public class AuthController {
    
        @Autowired
        private UserService userService;
    
        @GetMapping(value = {"", "/"})
        public String index() {
            return "redirect:login";
        }
    
        @GetMapping(value = {"/login"})
        public String login(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) throws IOException {
            if (userService.isAuthenticated()) {
                return "redirect:/home";
            }
            return "auth/login";
        }
    
        @GetMapping(value = { "/change-password"})
        public String changePassword(Model model) {
            return "auth/change-password";
        }
    
        @PostMapping(value = {"/change-password"})
        public String changePasswordSave(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) throws IOException {
            //validations and save
            return "redirect:/home";
        }
    }
```

Where might I be missing it here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you are missing that you should enable spring security DEBUG logs and check why you are being redirected in a loop. Most likely that you are redirected somewhere where you dont have permission that then redirects you into your filter and around we go....

Comment: This I have thoroughly. I think it takes more effort to ask a question here than just to enable logging in spring.

Comment: well considering you have not posted any of your logs in your question, i can only assume what you have put in writing, last time i checked no one here is a mind reader. Comments are only a reflection of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think I found a solution. I had to exclude the url from the filter itself.

So my custom filter then changes to:

```
public class ForcePasswordChangeFilter extends GenericFilter {

    private final UserService userService;

    public ForcePasswordChangeFilter(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request,
                         ServletResponse response,
                         FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (userService.isAuthenticated()) {
            User user  = userService.authenticatedUser();
            if (user.getShouldChangePassword()) {

                HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
                String path = httpServletRequest.getRequestURI();

                if ("/change-password".equals(path)) {
                    chain.doFilter(request, response);
                    return;
                }

                var httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
                httpResponse.sendRedirect("/change-password");
                return;
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }


}
```

I hope this will help someone in future!